# How can I get back a Gmail account I deleted forever 10 days ago?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

10 days ago I deleted forever by mistake a Gmail account that I need to recover (in the next couple of days).

Is this doable? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 6):

> ### **Recover a recently deleted Google Account**
>
> If you deleted your Google Account, you may be able to get it back. If it’s been a while since you deleted your account, you may not be able to recover the data in your account. If you recover your account, you'll be able to sign in as usual to Gmail, Google Play, and other Google services.
>
> 1. **[Follow the steps to recover your account](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery)**.
>
>    - You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer as best you can.
>    - If you're having trouble, try the tips to complete account recovery steps.
> 2. If your account is recovered, create a password that you haven't already used with this account. Learn how to create a strong password.
>
> ---
>
> **https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en**

---

> ### Undelete messages
>
> You can move messages out of your Trash if you deleted them in the last 30 days.
>
> How to recover messages from your Trash:
>
> - Log in to Gmail
> - Go to your Trash or click here: **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash**
> - Check the box next to any messages you want to move.
> - Click **Move to Inbox**.
> - Choose where you want to move the message to.

---

#### Note: Deleted emails (messages) from Trash can't be recovered!